# Creating a group by parameter for the get method in a generic repository for entity framework

Tags: linq, generics, entity-framework-6, iqueryable, func

I am using the repository pattern with Entity Framework as described in this article: [repository pattern with Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
In the part where the GenericRepository is described ([Generic Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-a-generic-repository)) there is a method which is used to get entities from the database set called Get. It has an orderBy but no groupBy. I am wondering how one might implement a groupBy in the same manner as the orderBy so that you can specify which field to group by dynamically on the entity.

What I have come up with is this:

```
Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IGrouping<string, TEntity>> groupBy = null
```

and then in the method code it should be used something like this:

```
if(groupBy != null)
{
    query = groupBy(query).ToList();
}
```

But this is not compiling since the IGrouping is not queryable. Does someone know how to point me in the right direction or has a solution to this?

Edit: The reason for doing this instead of using groupby on the returned list is for performance reasons. I want the groupby to be sent as an sql statement to the database and resolved there.

Comment: `GroupBy` has no benefits here, for performance reason you have to project to another entity type. Even worse, Generic Repository is anti-pattern which adds additional abstraction layer without benefits.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Without any sources or explanation about your statement that Generic Repository is an anti-pattern I can't seriously consider your claim. 
What I am trying to achieve is a re-usable and testable data access layer on top of the Entity Framework. So I have a Generic Repository with methods that are shared with all the specific repositories and unit tests to test those. Then in the specific repositories I have more specific methods for each repository with unit tests. In one of the repositories I would like to use group by in the way I specify in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping has no sense without projection. So you have to define new method which returns `IEnumerable` with new type.

I have added sample of such method. Also removed `includeProperties` because EF Core ignores Includes during grouping.

Usage sample:

```cs
_orderRepostory
   .GetGrouped(e => e.UserId, g => new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
```

And implementation:

```cs
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
 {
    ... // other code

    public virtual IEnumerable<TResult> GetGrouped<TKey, TResult>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> groupingKey,
        Expression<Func<IGrouping<TKey, TEntity>, TResult>> resultSelector,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? filter = null)
    {
        var query = dbSet.AsQueryable();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        return query.GroupBy(groupingKey).Select(resultSelector);
    }
 }
```

Comment: "Grouping has no sense without projection."  That is the key that I was missing. Seems obvious now.